# confusion on ancillary of gamma distribution

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

Here is the question. I am concerned about part (ii).

[image]

I found out, $T$ is complete sufficient statistic for $\beta$. Now I need to show that $X_{(i)}$ is ancillary. But, for of all, I can not find a explicit form of pdf of $X_{(i)}$. On the other hand, if I don't have to find that, then what is the other way to show $X_{(i)}$ is an ancillary?

Thanks for any help.

Note: [Basu's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem)

Comment: Is $\operatorname{gamma}(\alpha,\beta)$ supposed to mean that the distribution is $$ \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac x \beta \right)^{\alpha - 1} e^{-x/\beta}  \, \frac{dx} \beta \quad\text{for } x>0 $$ or that it is $$ \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} (\beta x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} (\beta\,dx) \quad \text{for } x>0 \text{ ?} $$ Both conventions are sometimes used. $\qquad$

Comment: I think the ancillary statistic that you need here is $X_{(i)}/T.$ The order statistic $X_{(i)}$ by itself is not ancillary. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy very sorry for this late reply. The second one of your first comment. Thanks for the second comment is the distribution here. I suspected that $X_{(i)}$ can not be an ancillary, but had no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\Pr(X_i\in A) & = \int_A \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} (\beta x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\beta x} (\beta\, dx) \\[10pt]
& = \int_{\beta A} \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} u^{\alpha-1} e^{-u} \, du \qquad \text{where } \beta A = \{\,\beta x:x\in A\,\}.
\end{align}

Let $Y_i= \beta X_i.$ Then
$$
\Pr(Y_i\in\beta A) = \Pr(X_i\in A),
$$
so $Y_i\sim\operatorname{gamma}(\alpha,1).$

Let $U= Y_1+\cdots+Y_n.$

Then $\dfrac{Y_{(i)}} U = \dfrac{X_{(i)}} T,$ so
$$
\Pr\left( \frac{X_{(i)}} T \in B \right) = \Pr\left( \frac{Y_{(i)}} U \in B \right)
$$
and the latter probability clearly does not depend on $\beta.$ Hence $X_{(i)}/T$ is an ancillary statistic.